# (standard_in) 1: syntax error in bash script

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I'm trying to generate some quasi random numbers to feed into a monte carlo simulation. I'm using bash. I seem to have hit a syntax error which I've narrowed down to being in this bit of code.

```
randno4=($RANDOM % 100001)
upper_limit4=$(echo "scale=10; 1*75.3689"|bc)
lower_limit4=$(echo "scale=10; 1*75.1689"|bc)
range4=$(echo "scale=10; $upper_limit4-$lower_limit4"|bc)
t_twall=`echo "scale=10; ${lower_limit4}+${range4}*${randno3}/100001" |bc`
echo "$t_twall"
```

Does anyone know why I the below output and not a value between 75.3689 and 75.1689 as that is what I would be expecting?

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Comment: `randno4=($RANDOM % 100001)` is not arithmetic evaluation. That will create a `randno4='([0]="25649" [1]="%" [2]="100001")'` array. Perhaps you meant `randno4='$(($RANDOM % 100001))'`?

Comment: I have several lines indentical to the first line apart from name of the variable. They seem to be fine.

Comment: You also use `$randno3` in the `t_twall` assignment line which is undefined.

Comment: That first line is *fine*. It just doesn't do what you think it does. Run that line and then run `declare -p randno4`. Then try `echo "$randno4"` vs. `echo "${randno4[1]}"`.

Comment: I believe the actual error here is from `bc` because of the `randno3` typo.

Comment: OK so is the zeroth point in the array a random number and if so is it between 0 and 100001? In my outputs I have not noticed any issues though I am new at this and just writing it. I do not get the same number as you for the zeroth element I get [0]="22737"

Comment: The initial element is the expansion of `$RANDOM` so it will be... wait for it... random. The point was that you are **not** applying a modulus operation to that value the way you were expecting. You are creating an array with **3** elements. The first of which (index `0`) is an unbounded random number. The second is `%`. The third is `100001`. For an array variable `arr` using `$arr` is equivalent to `${arr[0]}`. So when you use `$randno4` you are accessing `${randno4[0]}` which is the unbounded random number.

Comment: I don't want to mess you about but would be very very very useful for me to know whether or not the zeroth element is a random number **between 0 and 100001** or not. Is this the case? Is it some other limit e.g. the int limit or the double precision limit? Forget about the rest of the array. I don't want to bother a colleague about an academic paper they've already published if this is the case. If it is not then I should at least find out if they found and corrected the problem.

Comment: The bash man page explains the range of `RANDOM`. It is documented as "a random integer between 0 and 32767".

Comment: Thank you that was extremely useful. Bash man page - is that a website? Googling it gives you quite a lot of hits?

Comment: This was in a paper? Are you able to share what paper it was?

Comment: It is a paper in submission that I think is using the same code. I'm seeing the individual in question tomorrow. Don't want to unnecessarily panic anyone but should be checked out. I know she's a huge MATLAB fan and will probably have rewritten this to do all this stuff in MATLAB (I don't want to do this for various reasons that are too detailed to get into now). It isn't a paper about computer science I hasten to add, we (as you can tell from my basic questions) aren't a computer science department. Really appreciate your help on this. :)

Comment: The [`man` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/man) should be pretty much the first Linux command you learn. Here's the [`bash` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Comment: I gave +1 to the question (and @Etan), because it helped me to quickly understand where the odd error message came from (which was result from poorly written regex for `grep` that digs times from `ping` output, leading to malformed input for `bc`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first line should looks like :

```
randno4=$((RANDOM % 100001))
```

`(( ))` is bash arithmetic, with the leading `$` , the value is substituted : `$(( ))`

When you wrote

```
randno4=( )
```

you try to feed an ARRAY with a arithmetic expression with the wrong syntax.

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr

And finally, like [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) said, *You also use $randno3 in the t_twall assignment line which is undefined*

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This is correct for what it is covering (which is why I covered it in my comment) but this *isn't* the actual problem. That is fixing this does not fix the parsing error. The parse error is due to the `$randno3` typo.