# Why do I not see the full expected range of random numbers?

Tags: bash, random, bc

I would expect the below code to generate (quasi) random numbers between 0.9 and 1.0 for RH.

```
randno5=$((RANDOM % 100001))
upper_limit5=$(echo "scale=10; 1*1.0"|bc)
lower_limit5=$(echo "scale=10; 1*0.9"|bc)
range5=$(echo "scale=10; $upper_limit5-$lower_limit5"|bc)
RH=`echo "scale=10; ${lower_limit5}+${range5}*${randno5}/100001" |bc`
```

However, when I run this code I get value between 0.9 and 0.933(3sf). Why is this the case?

Comment: I covered the range of `RANDOM` in my comment to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134988/standard-in-1-syntax-error-in-bash-script).

Comment: You did, but I didn't get it first time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$RANDOM` is, at most, 32767:

```
   RANDOM Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between
          0 and 32767 is generated.  The sequence of random numbers may be
          initialized by assigning a value to RANDOM.  If RANDOM is unset,
          it  loses  its  special  properties,  even if it is subsequently
          reset.
```

Your modulus will have no effect as all generated numbers will be restricted to that range.